# API data not fetching when deployed next js 13

Tags: next.js, deployment, fetch, vercel, next.js13

I have an app that fetches data from [The Dog API](https://www.thedogapi.com). The data is rendered fine when I test on my local build, but when I deploy it, it doesn't fetch the data. I deployed Vercel and Netlify, and the both failed to fetch.

[Deployed website on Vercel](https://vercel.com/jae-the-castaway/doggy-worldcup)

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/jae-the-castaway/doggy-worldcup/blob/main/app/page.tsx)

```
// app/page.tsx

import Match from "./match";

const url =
  "https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=16&has_breeds=1&order=random";

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await fetch(`${url}&api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}`, {
    next: { revalidate: 10 },
  });
  const res = await data.json();

  return (
    <main className="h-screen">
      <Match dogs={res} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

- I checked this question, and tried  cache: 'no-store', but failed
- I tried deleting next: { revalidate: 10 }, but also failed

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by myself. I declared an environment variable for the api key on Vercel.

[check Vercel website](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables)